# How do I instantiate a BigInteger in a java static method like this?

Tags: java

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here because I get an error: 'Cannot instantiate the type BigInteger'

```
public static <BigInteger> List<BigInteger> convertIntegerListToStringList(List<String> existingList) {
      ArrayList<BigInteger> newList = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
      for(String item : existingList) {
        newList.add(new BigInteger(item));
      }
      return newList    
}
```

the part that is breaking the code is the public static `<BigInteger>` type parameter...but I have no idea why.  When i remove this typed parameter then the compilation error goes away.

Comment: It looks like the '<BigInteger>' a new type BigInteger is defiened locally for your function. If you check you import statement there would be no import statement for  BigInteger  (import java.math.BigInteger;) as a new type BigInteger is defiend locally. It may be heppening due to Generics. Either you need to correct the method signature or use  java.math.BigInteger(item).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the lone `<BigInteger>` from your method signature.  That syntax is for declaring type variables, which is not necessary in your case.  As written, you are declaring a "placeholder" called `BigInteger` that represents some unknown type.  Within the method, `BigInteger` refers to that unknown type (which, being unknown, cannot be instantiated) instead of referring to `java.math.BigInteger` as you intended.

Also, you should revisit your method name: your method performs the opposite operation that the name suggests, i.e., it converts a string list to a BigInteger list, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

Your method signature has wrong syntax. You should remove `<BigInteger>` to make function return object of type `List<BigInteger>`

```
  public static List<BigInteger> convertIntegerListToStringList(List<String> existingList)
  {
      ArrayList<BigInteger> newList = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
      for(String item : existingList) {
        newList.add(new BigInteger(item));
      }
    return newList;
  }
```

You also forgot about semicolon after return variable name.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static {ReturnType} {MethodName} ({Arguments})
```

This is how your method signature should be.
Cannot understand why you are having <BigInteger> after static in method signature.

Comment: If the OP hasn't used generics much before, it's an understandable mistake.  He is simply declaring a type variable when he need not be.